# Evaluate the limit without applying L'Hopital?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Can someone evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 3x}{x}$ without applying L'Hopital's rule to $\frac{\sin 3x}{x}$ to make it $\frac{3\cos 3x}{1}=3$?

Comment: Notice $\frac{\sin(3x)}{x}=\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x} \cdot 3$

Comment: @MatthewHolder  How do you show $\lim \frac {\sin x}x = 1$ without L'hopital (or equivalent)?